# Can't find target runtime in maven project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven

I'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE (Juno).

When I right click my project then click `Properties` I Can't find `target runtime`.

What I want to do is to connect my project with `Tomcat`.

I have other Maven project where I have `target runtime`, see below:

[image]

Any idea how to solve this?

== Update (solution): ==============================

[Maven project is not a Java EE project](http://www.thebestdata.com/zoom.htm?menutype=1&auto=8132)

Comment: You should add some more info to your question... Like what IDE are you on?

Comment: This looks like Eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have project facets enabled ?

Comment: Imho it's linked to facet configuration, are the same facets enabled in the 2 projects ? Otherwise is the java runtime version compliant with the targeted server runtime version ?

Answer (score 0):

Select Artifact id as a maven-archetype-webapp when you are creating a maven project.